# MySQL JDBC Web Program: error in DB config

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, web

I am trying to do a simple select from a MySQL database in a Java Web Project.

I have MySQL up and running on localhost. I have a database named "lab" and a table named "lab_user" with 1 record:

[image]
[image]

The issue is that every time that I try to select this 1 row from the program, I get an error saying that the table does not exist. So I believe that I may be doing something wrong with my DB config.

Below you can find my code, my web.XML and my context.XML.

Could you please help me to find out if there is anything wrong in here that is preventing from me to accessing the correct database?

THANK YOU

code

```
package DAO;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.sql.*;

import DTO.UserDTO;

public class UserDAO {

    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
    private ResultSet results = null;
    private static final String DATASOURCE_NAME = "java:comp/env/jdbc/lab";


    public void getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_NAME);
                connection = ds.getConnection();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public UserDTO selectUser(String userID) {

        //pessoal
        String id = "";
        String name = "";

        try {
            getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            results = statement.executeQuery("select * from lab_user where user_id = 1");

            if (results != null) {
                results.next();

                id = results.getString("id");
                name = results.getString("name");
            }
            results = null;
            ///

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            String error = "" + e;
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            cleanUp();

        }
        results = null;

        UserDTO uDTO = new UserDTO();
        uDTO.setName(name);
        uDTO.setID(id);

        return uDTO;
    }
```

web.XML

```
<description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/lab</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

context.XML

```
<Context>
  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="30" maxIdle="100" maxWait="10000" name="labDB" password="hacking" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" username="fabio"/>
</Context>
```

Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'LAB_USER' does not exist.

Comment: Is the error message from the code you've posted? The error complains about `LAB_USER` but in the code you have `lab_user`

Comment: @Joni: that shouldn't be a problem as in MySQL the table names / field names / etc are not case sensitive.

Comment: @SandorNemeth Table name case sensitivity depends on the file system. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @Joni thanks for the manual link.. I never had this kind of problem working on Unix/OSX/Windows..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `name` attribute in the context. It should look like this:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/lab" auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="30" maxIdle="100" maxWait="10000" name="labDB" password="hacking" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" username="fabio"/>
</Context>
```

Otherwise the application cannot access the defined data source.

Comment: There is a name. If you scroll to the right you will see. I had as name "labDB" as this is how I called my DB connection in Netbeans services, however I just changed it to your suggestion "jdbc/lab" and still did not work. I have same erro message saying table name invalid.

Comment: Yeah .. that's true, however this is how the application finds it, so it should be ```jdbc/lab```. Anyway... I'll try to create some sample code from the code you posted, because it's not obvious what's not working.. I'll come back when I have some more details

Comment: This would be absolutely awesome, I am waiting as I still could not understand what did not work.

Comment: Hey again .. sorry for the delay, had to dom some things .. anyway, your code seems fine, I have set up a test project on github [here](https://github.com/sandor-nemeth/stackoverflow-sample). You should be able to play around with it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look to the code:

```
   id = results.getString("id");
   name = results.getString("name");
```

The column names are wrong: they are user_id and user_name. I don't know why the error message was saying about table name.

It is amazing how these little things costs us a day of investigation.

Cheers